# WPF Path shape data binding: she don't update

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, pathgeometry

I'm attempting to bind the Data field on a WPF path object. I've tried two different approaches, but neither approach triggers an updated drawing.

Plan 1:

```
<Path Data="{Binding SegmentPoints, Converter={StaticResource PointsToBezier}}" ... />
```

SegmentPoints is an `ObservableCollection<Point>`. The converter returns a new StreamGeometry object. I expected that if I replaced a point in the collection the thing would redraw. That doesn't work. It does redraw if I trigger a PropertyChanged event for SegmentPoints.

Plan 2:

```
<Path ...><Path.Data><PathGeometry Figures="{Binding Figures}" .../>...
```

Then, inside the view model, I update things like my `BezierSegment.Point3`. Because the Point properties on the various segment types are DependencyProperties, I figured that I could update then and they would trigger and change up the tree. That's apparently not the case either.

So my questions:
Is there some way to manually trigger an update on a Path object? (If so, I could potentially use NotifyOnTargetUpdated.) Is there some way to configure the system such that point changes on segments will trigger a redraw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding in your first approach is only updated when the `SegmentPoint` property changes, i.e. is assigned to a new collection. Therefore it does not need to be an ObservableCollection. Just create a new collection and raise the [PropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx) event.

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private ICollection<Point> segmentPoints;

    public ICollection<Point> SegmentPoints
    {
        get { return segmentPoints; }
        set
        {
            segmentPoints = value;

            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SegmentPoints"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

However, in your second approach the trick is not to bind the PathGeometry's `Figure` property, but instead directly assign a PathFigureCollection, either in XAML or in code.

```
<Canvas Background="Transparent" MouseMove="Canvas_MouseMove">
    <Path Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="3">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathGeometry.Figures>
                    <PathFigureCollection x:Name="figures"/>
                </PathGeometry.Figures>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</Canvas>
```

Add segments and modify their properties in code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var segment = new BezierSegment(new Point(100, 0), new Point(200, 300), new Point(300, 100), true);
        var figure = new PathFigure();
        figure.Segments.Add(segment);
        figures.Add(figure);
    }

    private void Canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var firstSegment = figures[0].Segments[0] as BezierSegment;
        firstSegment.Point2 = e.GetPosition(sender as IInputElement);
    }
}
```

---

You may also create the `Figures` property in code, as shown below. The MainWindow class defines a `Figures` property which is assigned to the `Figures` property of the PathGeometry.

```
<Canvas Background="Transparent" MouseMove="Canvas_MouseMove">
    <Path Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="3">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry x:Name="geometry"/>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</Canvas>

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var segment = new BezierSegment(new Point(100, 0), new Point(200, 300), new Point(300, 100), true);
        var figure = new PathFigure();
        figure.Segments.Add(segment);

        Figures = new PathFigureCollection();
        Figures.Add(figure);

        geometry.Figures = Figures;
    }

    public PathFigureCollection Figures { get; set; }

    private void Canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var firstSegment = Figures[0].Segments[0] as BezierSegment;
        firstSegment.Point2 = e.GetPosition(sender as IInputElement);
    }
}
```

Apparently, updates to the path figures won't work when you bind the `Figures` property. The following binding assigns the figures once, but later changes aren't reflected in the Path.

```
// replace
// geometry.Figures = Figures;
// by
BindingOperations.SetBinding(geometry, PathGeometry.FiguresProperty,
    new Binding
    {
        Path = new PropertyPath("Figures"),
        Source = this
    });
```

Comment: Nevertheless not exactly an answer to "Is there some way to manually trigger an update on a Path object?".

Comment: I have a list of 2000 segments. I don't really like the idea of recreating 2000 segments whilst someone is dragging a single point on one of them around the screen.

Comment: I'm moving from GDI because of performance problems. My WPF implementation is not yet complete enough to answer the performance question.

Comment: I just tried your second example. It works as expected. I then retried my binding to PathFigureCollection with as few modifications to your example as possible, and it still didn't work. I'm baffled. (In essence, I set the window DataContext to self, added the binding in XAML, removed the PathGeometry.Figures element, made "figures" a public property, and moved InitializeComponent to the bottom of the constructor.)

Comment: Please see my other edit for how to assign the Figures property in code.

Comment: Thanks for the good examples. I had wanted the PathFigure to be in my ViewModel, rather than in the code-behind. It seems that scenario is not supported by WPF.

Comment: Or we're missing something, although I can't imagine what.

Comment: @Clemens you saved my day, sir. Not sure why binding alone doesn't work on approach 2. Spent quite a few hours playing with converters and trying different approaches and only by adding the path in code behind it worked. Guess I'll have my viewmodel fire an event to tell the UI to update itself...